# What is the difference between method and procedure?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What is the difference between 'method' and 'procedure'?

And

What is the difference between 'method' and 'procedure' in the context below.

'Traditional methods of generating energy' or 'Traditional procedures for generating energy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the definition for *method* starts with "A procedure..." there's not *much* difference.

- [Definition of *method*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/method)
- [Definition of *procedure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procedure)

So for all *practical* purposes they can be treated as interchangeable. That's not a very satisfying answer, though, so if there are slight hints of difference, they would be:

- *Procedure* implies *process*. It has steps, it implies activity over time.
- *Method* can imply intent, planning, and orderliness (as in the saying "There's method to his madness").

Comment: I add that rules & regulations may specify a **procedure** to be followed under certain circumstances, not a **method**. The latter may be a way of getting something done that usually works (and other methods may also be effective), but the former *must* be done.